# Preventing Renaming file extension in Telerik RadFileExplorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radfileexplorer

Hi I'm working with Telerik Radfileexplorer. I'm using this to upload only pdf documents. But after uploading the documents users can rename them. The control is allowing the users to rename file extension pdf aslo then if they change extension from pdf to some other then the file disappears. I tried to stop the behavior by following one of the post from Telerik forums but still the file is disappearing. The code and the form link are as follows.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/renaming-file-disallow-extensions-cancel-move

```
function explorerMove(explorer, args)
{
    //check if the event is fired by Rename command
    if (args.get_newPath().search("/") < 0) {
        if (!args.get_item().isDirectory()) { //check if the renamed item is file or folder

            var orgExt = args.get_path().substring(args.get_path().lastIndexOf("."));
            var newExt = args.get_newPath().substring(args.get_newPath().lastIndexOf("."));

            if (orgExt != newExt) {
                alert("Changing the file extension is not allowed");
                args.set_cancel(true); //cancel further execution of the command
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here even though the default behavior is canceled by using args.set_cancel(true); the file extension is still changing and file is disappearing. I thought of way to assign old path to new path in the if condition if(orgExt != newExt) but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: You had MVC as tag, can you confirm you are using webforms? The UI for ASP.NET AJAX does not support MVC and this may be the cause for the code not working.

Comment: I'm not using MVC for development i'm using regular asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this feature is supported out of the box with a property:

```
<telerik:RadFileExplorer runat="server" ID="FileExplorer1">
    <Configuration AllowFileExtensionRename="false"></Configuration>
</telerik:RadFileExplorer>
```